# Microsoft Project Server

Tags: project-server

I am trying to find the CAL counts on Project Server 2010 and is there any way to find them out?

1. Project Server Device CAL's
2. Project Server User CAL's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to identify the CAL type itself from the device (or via Project). You need to find the information from your reseller about the license type you selected.